# How to solve $\arcsin{(\phi)} = \cos(\phi)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How would you proceed $\arcsin{(\phi)} = \cos{(\phi)}$?

I've tried expressing $\arcsin{(\phi)}$ as a $\cos^{-1}$ to simplify things, but I couldn't figure it out.

It is possible to solve analytically?

Comment: Can you solve $x = \sin(\cos x)$ analytically? The best you can do is a numerical solution.

Comment: How would you do that? Taylor Series?

Comment: With a computer. For $-1 < x < 1$ find the zeros of $f(x) = sin(cos(x))-x$.

Comment: Taylor series are a bit yucky, since $\cos 0=1$. Newton's method is the obvious thing.

Comment: Ambiguous: $sin^{-1}(x)$ might get interpreted as $arc sin(x)$ or as $\frac{1}{sin(x)}$.

Comment: In case it is to be interpreted as $1/\sin(x)$, the solution is simple. The given equation is equivalent to $\sin(x)\cos(x) = 1$. Using the double angle formula gives $\sin(2x) = 2$, which has no real solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a quick script using Newton's Method:

```
from math import sin, cos

def f(x):
    return sin(cos(x)) - x

def f_deriv(x):
    return sin(x) * (-cos(cos(x))) - 1

def newton(x_n):
    return x_n - f(x_n) / f_deriv(x_n)

x = 0

for i in range(10):
    print(f"Current result after pass {i}: {x}")
    x = newton(x)
```

After some passes, to 16 decimal places, the result is $0.6948196907307875...$

Answer (score 0):

*Just for your curiosity.*

Without numerical method, use one single iteration of Newton-like methods of order $n$. This would generate the sequence of approximated values

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \phi_n &\text{method} \\
 2 &  1 & \text{Newton} \\
 3 &  \frac{2}{3} & \text{Halley} \\
 4 &  \frac{9}{13} & \text{Householder} \\
 5 &  \frac{52}{73} & \text{no name} \\
 6 &  \frac{365}{529} & \text{no name} \\
 7 &  \frac{1058}{1513} & \text{no name}    \\
 8 &  \frac{1869}{2693} & \text{no name}
   \\
 9 &  \frac{366248}{526289} &   \text{no name} \\
 10 &  \frac{1578867}{2272843} &    \text{no name} \\
 11 &  \frac{68185290}{98085043} &   \text{no name} \\
 12 &  \frac{1078935473}{1552932349} &    \text{no name}
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\frac{1078935473}{1552932349}=0.69477$$ while the exact solution is $0.69482$